# cakephp app execution stops when I try to save model. No error, nothing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Am working on a cakephp 2 app that I adopted.  When I try to save something, the application just stops.  This is the source code:

```
        $getConference = ClassRegistry::init('Conference')->find('first', ["conditions" => ["conference_id"=>$_GET['conf'] ]]);

        $checkTokenModel = ClassRegistry::init('User');
        $checkToken = $checkTokenModel->find('first', ["conditions" => ["remember_token"=>$_GET['token'] ]]);

        if ($getConference && $checkToken) {

            $checkToken['User']['remember_token'] = $this->generateToken();

            $this->log("Made it here!");

            if ($checkTokenModel->save($checkToken)) {
                $this->log("Saved");
            }
            else {
                debug($checkTokenModel->invalidFields());
                return false;
            }


            $this->log("Saved new token");

            $session->write('auth', true);
            $session->write('conferenceId', $_GET['conf']);


            $this->redirect('/');
            $this->log("Should be at home page.");

        }
```

I get "Made it here!" in the log, and that's the end of it.  Nothing else is executed.  Cannot get any error output.

This is happening on my local, vagrant machine.  I'm using the scotch-box vagrant machine, if that helps.  When we push it to a Cent-Os production server, this issue goes away.

What's going on here?

[EDIT]
The User model does not have any before methods.

Comment: $checkTokenModel  might not be getting reference of User Model. Check if there is any spelling mistake. Also check if there is any error log (error.log) generated in tmp/logs folder of your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  checkToken, after the find, is the record I'm looking for, so $checkTokenModel is getting the reference to User Model.  Very confident there are no spelling errors.  error.log is empty.